# Double border on one side

Tags: html, css, border

I currently have an element that has a solid border along one side of it, how would I go about making the border a double line?

The code for the current border is found below...

```
border-top:1px solid #CCC;
```

Comment: Here's why everyone is downvoting this: it shows no research or effort. A simple web search would have told you the answer. Did you even try "double border css" as a search term? Or look at a resource documenting the border property (even the frowned-upon W3CSchools has the right answer)?

Comment: @GregPettit W3Schools* (they have nothing to do with the W3C ;) )

Comment: I did some research and w3schools tutorial was my first point of call. Unfortunately for border-top it was not clear at all, it seemed to imply that 'solid' and 'double' were both required and I got confused when trying to put them together. I also had the border set to 1px because I want each of the lines to be 1px wide but this doesn't work with the double style type, therefore confusing me further.

Comment: I admit to having forgotten about the 'double' property. So this question helped remind me. Although, I don't think I have ever had a need for it. This CSS3 technique is probably more useful: http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2010/12/04/emulating-differently-colored-double-borders-with-css3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
border-top:3px double #CCC;
```

there is a double style type.

Comment: It's worth actually mentioning that the border width must be at least 3px in order to actually see the results, otherwise it *appears* as `solid`.

Comment: @Madmartigan ah, you are correct... I guess I didn't explain that :P